# my program is very simple but appear: "Sorry, the project has been stopped"

Tags: android

When I run a  program on a virtual and physical device and click on the button, the following message will appear:
"Sorry, the project has been stopped"

This app is designed for Android 4.0+
I tested on Different Android models

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private Button button;
        private TextView textview;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_1);
            Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_1);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    change();
                }
            });
        }
        private void change() {
            textview.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
}
```

Thank you very much
The problem was solved
the problem is here:

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_1);
```

textview is defined.so

```
textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_1);
```

is correct.

Comment: May you provide exception stack trace (from console/logcat)?

Answer (score 1):

Your `textview` is not visible to `change()`

```
private TextView textview  = null;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_1);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View view) {
            change(); 
        } 
    }); 
} 
private void change() { 
    if(textview!=null)
        textview.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

Comment: I did not care
Your answer is correct
Thank you very much

Comment: @MahdiPezeshki if that was useful, please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

- create new field in your class (for your views)
- assign them value (in `onCreate()`)
- use them

```
public class A extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Create new fields for your views
    private TextView textview;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Assign them View (from inflated layout)
        textview = findViewById(R.id.textview_1);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button_1);


        // Set listener
        button.setOnClickListener(view -> change());
    }

    private void change() {
        // Here you can use this view because it has value
        // (was assigned in 'onCreate()' method)
        textview.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not care
Your answer is correct
Thank you very much